# How to prevent closing the menu in angular material2?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have in my app a material menu.

https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

I want to prevent closing the menu when I click inside the menu.

Any ideas please?

`Link to my:`[app](http://plnkr.co/edit/7PDsaThRxyoGM6FoXImZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Event.stopPropagation()` [like so](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3lWiO5Ap1eBGB5o5HNU?p=preview).

Comment: nice I like that :)